# Query nested class and return the all root document in MongoDB via C# driver 2.1

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called 'Projects'.
In every **Project** I have subDocuments called **Structures** that included another subDocuments called **StructureProperties**.

I wish to get the **Property by the 'userId' and also it's ROOT using the C# driver 2.1** (userId - found in every Properties subDocuments).

my Project class look like that:

```
public interface IGeneralProject
{
    [BsonId]
    ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    List<GeneralStructure> GeneralStructures { get; set; } 
}
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ProjectOne), typeof(ProjectTwo))]
public class GeneralProject : IGeneralProject
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<GeneralStructure> GeneralStructures { get; set; }
}
```

Structure class:

```
public interface IGeneralStrucute
{
    ObjectId StructureId { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    List<GeneralStructureProperty> StructureProperties { get; set; } 
}

[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Structure), typeof(Houseware))]
public class GeneralStructure : IGeneralStrucute
{
    public ObjectId StructureId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<GeneralStructureProperty> StructureProperties { get; set; }
}
```

and the last one StructureProperty:

```
public interface IGeneralStructureProperty
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
}

[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Propery), typeof(Office))]
public class GeneralStructureProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried LINQ to query that but got stuck...

here some of my attempts:

1.

```
            return (from project in projectCollection.AsQueryable()
            from generalStructure in project.GeneralStructures
            from generalStructureProperty in generalStructure.StructureProperties
            where generalStructureProperty.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId)
            select new GeneralProject()
            {
                Id = project.Id, Name = project.Name, GeneralStructures = new List<GeneralStructure>()
                {
                    new GeneralStructure()
                    {
                        StructureId = generalStructure.StructureId, Name = generalStructure.Name, StructureProperties = new List<GeneralStructureProperty>()
                        {
                            new GeneralStructureProperty()
                            {
                                Name = generalStructureProperty.Name, UserId = generalStructureProperty.UserId
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).ToList();
```

2.

```
            var query = from project in projectCollection.AsQueryable()
                    from structure in project.GeneralStructures
                    from structureProperty in structure.StructureProperties
                    where structureProperty.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId)
                    select // where I got stuck...
```

3.

```
            var query =
            projectCollection.AsQueryable()
                .Select(project => project)
                .Where(
                    project =>
                        project.GeneralStructures.Any(
                            structure =>
                                structure.StructureProperties.Any(
                                    property => property.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId)))).ToList();
```

It very important to say that I could make that query and get good results, but I have been got the all Project document with *all of is subDocuments** instead of getting the Project with the specific Structure and the specific StructurePropery ('ROOT' of the node).

Comment: Can you show what operations did you try?

Comment: edit my Q (added 3 examples)..

Comment: I think you should provide exact model - what do you want to return from the query? Eg. in pseudo-code or something.

Comment: I want to return list of <Project with one structure, that inside it, it have one or more property of the same user>

Comment: Well it's look like it will work, but I'm thinking it's not so effective, can I get that results, without searching for  three times the userId?

Comment: I don't see faster solution. It depends on your db schema. I think you should  consider and rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that option :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return only the root document `GeneralProject` (as you mentioned in the subject)? You can try this:

```
var collection = mongoContext.GetCollection<GeneralProject>(); //your implementation here

var result = await collection
            .Find(x => x.GeneralStructures.Any(y => y.StructureProperties.Any(z => z.UserId == {user id here})))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or if you want to return `GeneralProject` and single `GeneralStructureProperty` with user id, you can try project it dynamically:

```
var result = await collection
            .Find(x => x.GeneralStructures.Any(y => y.StructureProperties.Any(z => z.UserId == {user id here})))
            .Project(
                    p => new
                    {
                        GeneralStructureProperty = p.GeneralStructures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StructureProperties.Any(z => z.UserId == {user id here})),
                        GeneralProject = p
                    })
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I didn't test it on real database and I suppose, these operations could be complicated for large amounts of data in db. But it based on your db architecture.

**EDIT:**

According to your comments:

```
var result = await collection
             .Find(x => x.GeneralStructures.Any(y => y.StructureProperties.Any(z => z.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId))))
             .Project(
                p => new
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Structure = p.GeneralStructures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StructureProperties.Any(z => z.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId)))
                })
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

result.Structure.StructureProperties = result.Structure.StructureProperties.Where(x => x.UserId == ObjectId.Parse(userId)).ToList();
```

Now you should retrieve project id, project name and structure with properties (with expected userId). Adjust my suggestion to your needs.

Comment: Did you try above queries?

Comment: yes, it returns the all doc of the project, including subdocs that didn't belonging